# How do you make a PyArrow Dataset out of an IO stream?

Tags: pyarrow

I have a python program reading a parquet file in as a filereader, and am trying to use this to construct a pyarrow dataset. I am able to read the filereader into a pyarrow table, using:

```py
    import pyarrow.parquet as pq

    table = pq.read_table(file_reader)
```

However, passing the filereader directly to the dataset initializer gives an error. This makes sense because the pyarrow documentation shows the ds.dataset function does not accept a filereader as a data source:

```py
    import pyarrow.dataset as ds

    dataset = ds.dataset(file_reader) # TypeError: Expected a path-like, list of path-likes or a list of 
                                       # Datasets instead of the given type
```

A current work-around I'm trying is reading the stream in as a table, and then reading the table as a dataset:

```py
    import pyarrow.parquet as pq
    import pyarrow.dataset as ds

    table = pq.read_table(input_stream)
    dataset = ds.dataset(table)
```

However, I'm not sure this is a valid workaround for a Dataset, because the dataset may expect the table being passed to be backed by an underlying file, which it is not.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely certain what you mean by a "filereader".  Arrow has a C++ class `parquet::arrow::FileReader` but I don't think `pyarrow` has documented bindings for that although it is used internally for functions like `pyarrow.parquet.ParquetFile.iter_batches`.

Either way, the answer is probably that you cannot create a dataset from a file reader but you also probably don't need to.

Typically datasets are used to create a scanner which can then be used directly for iterative processing (possibly filtering or projecting the data) or as input to something like `pyarrow.dataset.write_dataset`.

```
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
import pyarrow.dataset as ds

tab = pa.Table.from_pydict({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': ['x', 'y', 'z']})
pq.write_table(tab, '/tmp/foo.parquet')

parquet_file = pq.ParquetFile('/tmp/foo.parquet')
schema = parquet_file.schema_arrow
itr = parquet_file.iter_batches()

scanner = ds.Scanner.from_batches(itr, schema=schema, columns=['a'], filter=ds.field('b') == 'y')
print(scanner.to_table())
```

The main thing that is missing here is you won't have any filter pushdown.  Obviously we can't do any partition-based filtering because there is only one file but we also don't get to use parquet's statistics-based row group filtering.

You will also need to make sure when you create the file to only ask for the columns you need (e.g. the one's selected by the scanner's projection and filter).  Otherwise it will load those columns in memory only for the scanner to drop them later.